# Error Found: Java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: php, android, post, retrofit

I keep on getting the error from my Android App:

> *Java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $*

I was just trying to test a post method from my Android App to my custom API.

I can successfully do the GET Method but apparently when I try to do a post method I encounter an error.

This is my custom API:

```php
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/config.php';

class API_READ {
    function Select(){
        $db = new Connect;
        $timecards = array();
        $data = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM employee_timecards_it100test ORDER BY id');
        $data->execute();

        while($OutputData = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $timecards[$OutputData['id']] = array(
                'id'               => $OutputData['id'],
                'employee_id'      => $OutputData['employee_id'],
                'department_id'    => $OutputData['department_id'],
                'position_id'      => $OutputData['position_id'],
                'timecard_date'    => $OutputData['timecard_date'],
                'year'             => $OutputData['year'],
                'month'            => $OutputData['month'],
                'day'              => $OutputData['day'],
            );
        }
        return json_encode(array_values($timecards));
    }
}

class API_CREATE{

    private $db;
    private $input;

    function __construct(){
        $this->db = new Connect;
        $this->input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);     
    
    }

    function Create(){
        $query = "INSERT INTO employee_timecards_it100test (employee_id, department_id, position_id, timecard_date, year, month, day) 
        VALUES (:employee_id, :department_id, :position_id, :timecard_date, :year, :month, :day)";
        
        $statement = $this->db->prepare($query);

        $statement->execute(array(
            ':employee_id'      => $this->input['employee_id'],
            ':department_id'    => $this->input['department_id'],
            ':position_id'      => $this->input['position_id'],
            ':timecard_date'    => $this->input['timecard_date'],
            ':year'             => $this->input['year'],
            ':month'            => $this->input['month'],
            ':day'              => $this->input['day']
        ));
        $id = $this->db->lastInsertId();
        return json_encode(array('id' => $id));
    }

}


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $API = new API_CREATE;
    header ('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo $API->Create();
} else {
    $API = new API_READ;
    header ('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo $API->Select();
}


?>
```

This is part of my MainActivity1:

```
Methods methods = RetrofitClient.getRetrofitInstance().create(Methods.class);
Call<Post> call = methods.createPost(empId, deptId, posId, timecardDate, year, month, day);

call.enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Post> call, Response<Post> response) {
        String strOutput = "";
        strOutput =  "Id : " + response.body().getId();
        strOutput = strOutput + "\nEmployee : " + response.body().getEmployee_id();
        strOutput = strOutput + "\nDeptId : " + response.body().getDepartmen_id();
        strOutput = strOutput + "\nPositionId : " + response.body().getPosition_id();
        lblOutput.setText(strOutput);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Post> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.d("Error123: ",t.getMessage().toString());
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity1.this, "Error Found:" + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

My Retrofit Client:

```
public class RetrofitClient {
    private static Retrofit retrofit;
    //private static String BASE_URL = "https://reqres.in/";
    private static String BASE_URL = "MY CUSTOM API Link";
    public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class Model {
    private String id, employee_id, department_id, position_id, timecard_date, year, month, day;

    public Model(String employee_id, String department_id, String position_id, String timecard_date, String year, String month, String day) {
        this.employee_id = employee_id;
        this.department_id = department_id;
        this.position_id = position_id;
        this.timecard_date = timecard_date;
        this.year = year;
        this.month = month;
        this.day = day;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getEmployee_id() {
        return employee_id;
    }

    public String getDepartmen_id() {
        return department_id;
    }

    public String getPosition_id() {
        return position_id;
    }

    public String getTimecard_date() {
        return timecard_date;
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public String getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public String getDay() {
        return day;
    }

}
```

Methods:

```
public interface Methods {

   // @FormUrlEncoded
   // @POST("/api/users")
    //Call<Model> getUserData(@Field("name")String name,@Field("job") String job);

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/API")
    Call<Post> createPost(
            @Field("employee_id") String employee_id,
            @Field("department_id") String department_id,
            @Field("position_id") String position_id,
            @Field("timecard_date") String timecard_date,
            @Field("year") String year,
            @Field("month") String month,
            @Field("day") String day
    );
}
```

I did try to isolate the issue, using the code on my Android Studio, I was able to do a Post Method using https://reqres.in/

That is why I'm assuming there's something wrong with my custom API.

In Postman, I can successfully do Post by inputting BODY RAW data.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Is this a PHP problem or an Android problem? Please check whether sending the request is the problem (in your Android app), or handling it (on your server, in PHP)

Comment: I think this is PHP-Side problem. because I did try to adjust my code to call post and get methods from https://reqres.in/ to check if my android code is working, and it works.

But when I try to have my android code do a post method with my custom PHP API.
the error on the title is what I encounter.

When I try post method in postman, this is the response I encounter:

{
    "id": "4895"
}

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. If this is a PHP problem, remove the other parts